# AssertionError on kafka consumer

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-kafka

I'm trying to process Meetup RSVP streaming api with kafka.

The process is below:

- Start Zookeeper
- Start Kafka
- Start Cassandra
- Run rsvp_producer.py
- Run rsvp_consumer.py <- I'm here.

When I try to run the rsvp_consumer.py, I got the error below in Terminal on Mac.

```
$ python rsvp_consumer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rsvp_consumer.py", line 12, in <module>
    metadata_broker_list = kafka_brokers_list)
  File "/Users/kimitakanakazawa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 169, in __init__
    assert not configs, 'Unrecognized configs: %s' % configs
AssertionError: Unrecognized configs: {'metadata_broker_list': ['localhost:9092']}
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the configuration key `metadata_broker_list` changed to `bootstrap_servers` in recent releases. You can either edit rsvp_consumer.py, or you can install an older version of kafka-python: `pip install kafka-python==0.9.5`

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem exactly, for my case, that is because the wrong way to init the kafka consumer. I changed it to:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='192.168.33.10:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest')
consumer.subscribe(['topic_name'])
```

then it works